# Problems querying JSON nested hash response in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash, nested

Cannot seem to solve this problem:

I'm getting JSON nested hash responses from Lastfm and everything works fine when the response is structures as such:

```
{"topalbums" =>{"album" =>{"name =>"Friday Night in Dixie"}}}
```

However if the artist does not have a top album the response is structured this way and I get a NoMethodError undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass.

```
{"topalbums" =>{"#text"=>"\n   ", "artist"=>"Mark Chestnutt"}}
```

What I want to do is query the response so I do not keep getting this error.

Here is my method:

```
 def get_albums
   @albums = Array.new
   @artistname.each do |name|
      s = LastFM::Artist.get_top_albums(:artist => name, :limit => 1)
      r = JSON.parse(s.to_json)['topalbums']['album']['name']
      @albums.push(r)
   end
 end
```

which gives me exactly what I want if the artist has a top album, what I need to do is somehow add a condition to query the keys in the nested hash. However, I cannot seem to grasp how to do this as when I add this line of code to check key values:

```
s.each_key { |key, value| puts "#{key} is #{value}" }
```

the output I get is this:

> topalbums is

so topalbums key does not have a value associated with it.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
  def get_albums
   @albums = Array.new
   @artistname.each do |name|
      s = LastFM::Artist.get_top_albums(:artist => name, :limit => 1)
      if s.has_key?('album') #I know this won't work but how can I query this?
         r = JSON.parse(s.to_json)['topalbums']['album']['name']
         @albums.push r 
      else
         @albums.push(name << "does not have a top album")
      end
   end
 end
```

How can I fix this so I get 'Mark Chestnut does not have a top album' instead of the `NoMethodError`? Cheers

Comment: which line are you getting the error on?

Comment: Was getting the error when parsing the response but it is fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Hash#fetch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) default values, I would do as below:

#### No `"album"` key present

```
hash = {"topalbums" =>{"#text"=>"\n   ", "artist"=>"Mark Chestnutt"}}
default_album = {"name" => "does not have a top album"}
hash["topalbums"].fetch("album", default_album)["name"]
#=> "does not have a top album"
```

#### `"album"` key present

```
hash = {"topalbums" =>{"#text"=>"\n   ", "artist"=>"Mark Chestnutt", "album" => {"name" => "Foo"}}}
hash["topalbums"].fetch("album", default_album)["name"]
#=> "Foo"
```

So if the hash does not have an `"album"` key `fetch` defaults to `default_album` else it uses the key it find as in the second case